# Extract Email: Name: Phone: from adjacent lines from file of similar records

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a text file with a list similar to this:
These are all on separate lines in my text file

```
Email: jonsmith@emailaddie.com 
Name: Jon Smith
Phone Number: 555-1212
Email: jonsmith@emailaddie.com
Name: Jon Smith
Phone Number: 555-1212
Email: jonsmith@emailaddie.com
Name: Jon Smith
Phone Number: 555-1212
```

I am attempting to take the group: [email, name, phone]  combinations and export as another text file, with each group on a separate line.

Here is what I have tried so far: (If I can get it to print to the terminal correctly, I know how to write to another file.

I am running Ubuntu Linux

```
import re

stuff = list()

#get line
with open("a2.txt", "r") as ins:
    array = []
    for line in ins:
        if re.match("Email Address: ", line):
            array.append(line)
            if re.match("Phone Number: ", line):
                array.append(line)
                if re.match("Name: ", line):
                    array.append(line)
                    print(line)
```

Comment: Is the indentation of the code you pasted correct?

Comment: @DroidX86 I believe so, yes.

Comment: So you only want to print the line if all the 3 conditions match?

Comment: Do you know [what `re.match` does](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re.match#re.match)?

Comment: @DroidX86 correct. This challenge project started with me going through 3,000 PDFs, converting them to text individual text files and then scraping the names, emails and phone numbers out of them using python. But the output file ended up putting the persons info on separate lines. I’m attempting to correct this with another py

Comment: When I wrote the py to extract the data originally I used “startswith” because each line I want to extracts starts with Email: , Phone Number:, and Name:

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in comments, you are looking at the same line through the nested `if` statements. No line in your sample matches all three regular expressions, so that code would never extract anything. There is no need to use regular expressions here, anyway; the simple `line.startswith()` is entirely sufficient for looking for individual static strings or small sets of static strings.

Instead, you want to

```
array = []
for line in ins:
    if line.startswith('Email Address:'):
        array.append(<<Capture the rest of the line>>)
    elif line.startswith('Name: '):
        array.append(<<Capture the rest of the line>>)
    elif line.startswith('Phone Number: '):
        array.append(<<Capture the rest of the line>>)
        print(array)
        array = []
```

This simple structure is sufficient if the lines are always in exactly the same order. If you have to cope with missing optional lines or mixed order, the program will need to be slightly more complex.

You will notice that this code (with partial pseudo-code) still is rather repetitive. You want to avoid repeating yourself, so a slightly better program might just loop over the expected phrases in sequence.

```
fields = ('Email Address: ', 'Name: ' , 'Phone Number: ')
index = 0
array = []
for line in ins:
     if line.startswith(fields[index]):
        array[index] = line[len(fields[index]):-1]
     else:
        raise ValueError('Expected {0}, got {1}'.format(field[index], line))
    index += 1
    if index >= len(fields):
        print(array)
        array = []
        index = 0
```

This is slightly harder to read at first, but you should quickly be able to make sense of it. We have an `index` which tells us what value out of `fields` to expect, and print the collected information and wrap the `index` back to zero when we run out of `fields`. This also conveniently lets us refer to the length of the expected string, which we need when we extract the substring after it out of the line. (The `-1` is to get rid of the newline character which exists at the end of every line we read.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the parameters(Email, Name, and Phone number) will be coming in the same order given then the code will work fine, if not then handle this in "else" statement. You can save incomplete values or raise an exception for the same.

```
with open("path to the file") as fh:
# Track the status for a group
counter = 0
# List of all information
all_info = []
# Containing information of current group
current_info = ""
for line in fh:
    if line.startswith("Email:") and counter == 0:
        counter = 1
        current_info = "{}{},".format(current_info, line)
    elif line.startswith("Name:") and counter == 1:
        counter = 2
        current_info = "{}{},".format(current_info, line)
    elif line.startswith("Phone Number:") and counter == 2:
        counter = 0
        all_info.append("{}{},".format(current_info, line).replace("\n",""))
        current_info = ""
    else:
        # You can handle incomplete information here.
        counter = 0
        current_info = ""
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was approaching this completely wrong. The hardest part for me about programming has to be the approach, the thought process, that is involved before, even writing a single line of code.